# Retrieve value of root variables in state machine workflow, during resume

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a State Machine workflow which I am self-hosting within a WorkflowApplication.
When I resume a persisted workflow, I need to be able to extract the value of a given root-level variable (hence it should be in scope) - out of the workflow and into my hosting environment - just to be clear, I need to access the variables from OUTSIDE of the workflow.

I have followed instructions here: [HOW to get Context of WorkflowApplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397114/how-to-get-context-of-workflowapplication) but I am not receiving any events (upon resumption) that would contain the values of the root-level variables.
I am starting to think that the 'resume' of a workflow does not fire any tracking that allows one to grab root level variables.

Does anybody have a clearer explanation, perhaps a test harness?

Thanks

Comment: You can easily pass values into the workflow when resuming bookmarks; why not just slide them in that way?

Comment: Hi Will, thanks, but I have amended my question to be clearer - I need to pull the variables out of the workflow - it is self-hosted, and I need my exe to be able to access these variables. I could possible wire something up with custom activities, but I dont want to require that WF designers use custom activities.

Comment: Do you own the activity that bookmarks the workflow?  As in, can you change the code?

Comment: No I won't be changing the workflow. I know how to do it by putting custom activities in the workflow, but that is not acceptable. The link that I refer to talks about obtaining variables through tracking and I need to do it this way. It allegedly works, but I cannot get it to function.

Comment: Are these variables changed at all by the workflow prior to the bookmark?

Comment: Yes the variables are changed before, after, all over the place.

Comment: And, I assume, these variables hold primitives and immutables (e.g., string, int), right?  No mutable reference types?

Comment: Actually they hold both structs and classes.

Comment: I'd have said, "hold a reference to the instances that go in", but if you're passing a struct in by value that changes, that won't help you.

Comment: The other alternative would be to get the root ModelItem of the workflow at the time of bookmarking and dig down inside of it.  If you've ever done this before, you will know that it smells.  The design is failing, and all you have left are dirty hacks.

Comment: Thanks Will - do you have any idea what they are referring to in the Tracking hyperlink that I attached to the document? This is specifically the implementation that I am after - not any of these 'dirty hacks'. Thanks